# What is the probability that three living people in the same family will celebrate their birthdays on exactly the same day.

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, birthday

I celebrate my birthday on the same day as one of my grandchildren. Just wonder how rare it would be for three people in the same family to celebrate their birthdays on the same day.

Comment: That depends on how many people are in the family.

Comment: [Not as rare as you might initially think.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

Comment: Twins would affect this

Answer (score 1):

Let's work out for a family of four, $A,B,C,D$

So three share the same birthday, and one person is the odd person out.

- There are $4$ possible odd-person-out.
- This person could have any birthday, and $364$ days are left for the trio to share one in common, ignoring leap years

Thus $Pr = 4\times \frac{364}{365}(\frac{1}{365})^2, \approx\dfrac{1}{33398}$

Comment: Some people might add $(\frac{1}{365})^3$ if having three includes having four, though it makes a minimal difference here